# Anonymous account usage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a 2013 enterprise on premise farm and anonymous access is NOT enabled.
When I view usage reports (we have a 3rd party reporting tool called HarePoint) I see activity by the user anaoymous. This activity is usually greater than that of all the named AD users.

Also in the event viewer on the web front end I see this entry every hour on the hour. SQL database login for '2013_Config' on instance '2013_SQL' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Given this hourly repeat 24/7 I'm wondering if it could be a timer job definition but what timer job definition would run under the context of the anon account - in my view, none!

I'm not sure where to start digging to find out more. I have full control of the SharePoint and SQL environments so am able to provide more detail if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution for this issue. For the Warmup script (https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2014/02/21/sharepoint-2013-warm-up-script/) which was scheduled in Task Scheduler. I had to make sure that "Do not store password. The Task will only have access to local computer resources" is unchecked. Once you click "Ok", it will ask for password again, enter password and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will see this with anything that (tries to) performs a double-hop when NTLM is used. As NTLM is not capable of performing double-hop authentication, unlike Kerberos, the login identity is unknown and you'll see 'anonymous logon' in the SQL Server security logs.

If it is originating from SharePoint, you can find ULS entries that would be similar filtering by the 'Database' category.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. I have a scheduled task that runs hourly to "warm up" SharePoint IIS sites using the invoke-WebRequest cmdlet. 
Initially I was using Get-SPWebApplication and then looping through the web apps to warm each up. I changed this by hard coding the URLs and also commented out the UseDefaultCredentials parameter.

One or both of these changes has put an end to the errors.